# Add Required to Dynamically Created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a dynamically created `select` element as such:

```
var select  = document.createElement("select");
```

What I would like to do now is make this element `required`. I know how to manipulate classes, values, and text of dynamically created elements, but cannot figure out how to make the element `required`. I had read an answer from a similarly sounding question that:

```
select.rules("add", "required");
```

would work, but the browser comes back with the error `Uncaught TypeError: select.rules is not a function`. From what I've read this usually indicates a variable not being properly made for JQuery, so I tried changing the creation line to:

```
var select  = $("<select></select>");
```

But I received the same TypeError. Really all I am trying to do is add `required` to a dynamically created `select`, and any indication of a direction to take to do so would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
select.setAttribute("required", "");
```

OR

```
document.createElement("select").required = true;
```

Comment: `select.setAttribute("required", "");` worked when I amde select through `document.createElement("select");`. I assume this was mainly an issue of me confusing javascript and jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/z2f9mxa0/

```js
var select  = $("<select></select>");
$('body').append(select);

$('select').attr('required', "");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you open the browser debug panel, you will be able to see the required attribute set to **select** element i.e. dynamically added.

Comment: I realized my issue mainly was I wrote everything in javascript and was trying to use jquery functions on that. This does work for a jquery equivalent though, so thank you helping future headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var selectHTML ="<select>";
selectHTML += "<option value=''>Select one</option>";
selectHTML += "</select>";
newDiv.innerHTML = selectHTML;
document.getElementsByClassName("my-select")[0].appendChild(newDiv); 
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].required = true;
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="my-select">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```